# Import error web "no module named web"

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, web, python-import, web.py

I did an web application using web.py and after a while I realize that my python compiler was configure to use python2 instead of python3 (both are installed). With python2 my application was working but I got string in unicode so I try to execute my code using python3:

```
python3 mycode.py
```

But I get different kind of error, the lib urlparse was not found (this problem was cause by a new name in python3 which is urllib)  but I got a problem with:

```
import web
```

The return error is:

```
ImportError: No module named 'web'
```

I can't figure out where the problem come from.

Comment: Could you give more information if web.py is already installed etc. it looks like a basic error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web.py cannot work with python3, this is the linked to the gitub project.
https://github.com/webpy/webpy/issues/108

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have installed web in your python2 lib but you have none in python3 lib... Check it out